# Get currently playing media in Windows Media Player

Tags: java, windows, windows-media-player

How to get current played song in Windows media player using Java?  There's many question about this, but the answers are in C#. How to do that using Java - using library or there's WMP API?

Answer (score 1):

> ..current played song in Windows media player using java

Not on OS X or *nix, & not on this Windows 7 machine where I run VLC/WinAmp.  So you can take it that Java will not have an in-built API for it.

Java can use natives though, so do it in C# and call that from Java.

Answer (score 1):

I think [JIntellitype](http://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/) API will help you. It uses the JNI calls.

**Some use full reference for native calls:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx